# How to populate data into shopping cart in render after setting local storage with useEffect in react

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am creating a shopping cart and is running into an issue. A bit of context before touching the issue- I have a component here that contains the `addToCart` function whose job is to take an object that contains data about the item selected, check it against `cartItems` and if it is not present add it to `cartItems`. The change is this `cartItems`then triggers the useEffect hook which takes the data in `cartItems` and send its to the localStorage. So far so good.

The issue arises when I have to render the content the user has chosen from the local storage onto the render. Right now it is rendering all the items accept the item chosen last. Is there anyway I can make the objects that are sent to the localStorage appear on the render instantaneously?

Code is below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/global/layout/Layout';
import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from '../components/page-css/order.module.css';

const Order = () => {
    const [ menuItems, setMenuItems ] = useState(false);
    const [ cartItems, setCartItems ] = useState([]);

    const addToCart = (selectedItem) => {
        !cartItems.includes(selectedItem) ? setCartItems([ ...cartItems, selectedItem ]) : console.log('already added');
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
        },
        [ cartItems ]
    );

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Row>
                {/* <Menu xs={12} className={styles.cart} addToCart={addToCart}>
                    {this is the component inside which the menu items are. Do not pay much attention to this as it does not have anything to do with my current question}
                </Menu> */}

                <Col xs={12} className={styles.cart}>
                    <h2>Your Cart</h2>
                    {console.log(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Order;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly render from `cartItems` instead of `localStorage.getItem('cartItems')`. Also, if you want to show the data from the local storage when the component is mounted then you can update it into cartItems as the initial data.